# Why does vim allow integer division by zero?

Tags: vimscript, arithmetic

I just discovered that vim obviously allows division by zero:

```
:let a=42/0
:echo a
```

prints `2147483647` (which is the value of `a`).

Is this documented somewhere and why does vim allow division by zero?

Comment: Try `:echo 42/0.0` to see another result :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This behavior is documented under [eval section](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/eval.html):

```
When dividing a Number by zero the result depends on the value:
      0 / 0  = -0x80000000  (like NaN for Float)
     >0 / 0  =  0x7fffffff  (like positive infinity)
     <0 / 0  = -0x7fffffff  (like negative infinity)
    (before Vim 7.2 it was always 0x7fffffff)
```

Answer (score 15):

Here is why :

```
42 / 0 tends to +infinity
```

And how does Vim represent the largest number available ?

```
2147483647
```

See `:h limits`

Furthermore, the `float2nr` function documentation states :

```
When the value of {expr} is out of range for a |Number| the
result is truncated to 0x7fffffff or -0x7fffffff.  NaN results
in -0x80000000.
```

So you have here your 2 numbers : `+ 2147483647` and `- 2147483647`.

The last number `-2147483648` is used for representing the `NaN` value.

This is confirmed by the `eval` section on it (mea culpa: [@cuonglm posted](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/4632/1892) it just before me) :

```
When dividing a Number by zero the result depends on the value:
    0 / 0  = -0x80000000    (like NaN for Float)
   >0 / 0  =  0x7fffffff    (like positive infinity)
   <0 / 0  = -0x7fffffff    (like negative infinity)
```

As @VanLaser stated, this only work for integer, for floating point number you have more consistency :

```
 1/0.0     =  inf
 1/0.0 + 1 =  inf
 1/0.0 - 1 =  inf

-1/0.0     = -inf
-1/0.0 - 1 = -inf
-1/0.0 + 1 = -inf
```

Comment: In that case, why is division of a negative number by 0 not the minimum number? -> http://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/4623/why-is-division-of-a-negative-number-by-0-not-the-minimum-number

Comment: I've edited my question

Comment: 2147483647 certainly is *much* closer to zero than to infinity. So, to represent infinity with such a *small* number doesn't seem helpful, at least not to me.

Answer (score 2):

This behavior is useful in Calculus when using something called a Limit.

Lim n -> 0^+ of 1/n = +inf

This can also be written as:
As n -> 0^+, 1/n -> +inf

It is read like so..
As n approaches zero from the right, the function 1/n approaches positive infinity.

To see a visual explanation of this reasoning, pop over to
http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=limit+n-%3E0+of+1%2Fn

As for Vim-script specifically, AFAIK not many people do much more than logic and integer arithmetic with it.  It could be the case that this behavior seemed like a good idea at the time, and is merely a legacy artifact at this point.

Comment: Do you have a source for the last paragraph? Integer division by zero is undefined in C, any behaviour you see is dependent on the processor, etc.

Comment: Oh, you're right.  I'm removing the paragraph.