# Why is division of a negative number by 0 not the minimum number?

Tags: vimscript, arithmetic

Related to [Why does vim allow to divide by zero](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/4613/why-does-vim-allow-to-divide-by-zero), what's going on here?

```
:let a=-42/0
:echo a
-2147483647

:let b=a - 1
:echo b
-2147483648
```

Comment: @Nobe4's answer on the linked question is more than sufficient to answer this question, so this question is now a duplicate.

Answer (score 2):

It is because vim represents the signed integers on 32 bits which makes that `-2147483648` actually is the smallest number in Vim and not `-2147483647` as you could think.

```
let foo = -2147483647
echo foo - 1
=> -2147483648

let foo = -2147483648
echo foo - 1
=> 2147483647
```

On 32 bits the max value of an integer is `2^31-1` when the min value is `-2^31`. For an explanation of this different values see [this wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signed_number_representations#Two.27s_complement) about the two complement in the representation of signed integers.

Comment: See my edition on the linked question :) : `-2147483648` is used for representing `NaN`

Comment: @statox: this answer does not explain why -X/0 is -2147483647 instead of -2147483648.